# How to get signal in Qt from a printer when it finishes printing?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to get notifications in Qt for a printer but unfortunately couldn't find any solution. I've already tried to check the state but it never changes, it is always 'PrinterState::Idle'.

```
void Functions::print(QString fileName)
{
    printerTmr = new QTimer(this); 
    printerTmr->setInterval(2000); 
    connect(printerTmr, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(printerStateCheck())); 
    printerTmr->start(); //start checking the state of the printer

    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A6);
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
    QImage img(fileName);

    QSize size;
    QIcon icon;

    QPainter painter( &printer );
    int      w = printer.pageRect().width();
    int      h = printer.pageRect().height();
    QRect    page( 0, 0, w, h );

    QImage image(fileName);
    if (!image.isNull())
      icon.addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On);

    icon = icon;
    size = QSize(w,h);
    QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(size, QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On);
    ........

    //draw simulated landscape
    page.adjust( w/20, h/20, -w/20, -h/20 );
    painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(0,0),pixmap);

}

void Functions::printerStateCheck()
{

    if(printer.printerState() == QPrinter::PrinterState::Idle){
        qDebug()<<"PrinterState::Idle";
    }else if(printer.printerState() == QPrinter::PrinterState::Error){
        qDebug()<<"PrinterState::Error";
    }else if(printer.printerState() == QPrinter::PrinterState::Active){
        qDebug()<<"PrinterState::Active";
    }else if(printer.printerState() == QPrinter::PrinterState::Aborted){
        qDebug()<<"PrinterState::Aborted";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. There are a few odd things about your code (e.g. ` icon = icon;`) and you did not include the header. Please take a look at [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so chances are better that we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Printing possibility in Qt is hold very simple. [QPrinter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html) device represents a series of pages of printed output, and is used in almost exactly the same way as other paint devices such as [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) and [QPixmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html).

When printing directly to a printer on Windows or macOS, QPrinter uses the built-in printer drivers. On X11, [QPrinter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html) uses the Common Unix Printing System (CUPS) to send PDF output to the printer.

As an alternative, the [printProgram()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#printProgram) function can be used to specify the command or utility to use instead of the system default. (P.S.: but only on X11 system for pdf printing)

[QPrinter::printerState()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#printerState) Returns the current state of the printer. This may not always be accurate (for example if the printer doesn't have the capability of reporting its state to the operating system).

So like the Qt doc says it is on printer, printer drivers, printing subsystem and OS itself to provide the state. I think you have more luck with printing states under linux whith CUPS then in windows.

Try to use OS printing API directly.

Here is info with example code for WINAPI on [How to get the status of a printer and a print job](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/160129/how-to-get-the-status-of-a-printer-and-a-print-job)